# Solve $(ST-\lambda I)x=b$ in $O(n^2)$ for upper triangular $S,T$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

> Let $S,T\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be 2 upper triangular matrixes, and $ST-\lambda I$ be nonsingular where $I$ denotes the identity matrix of order $n$. Solve the system of linear equations in complexity $O(n^2)$ for $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$:
>   $$(ST-\lambda I)x=b$$

It's known that equations like $Uy=b$ for upper triangular $U$ can be solved in complexity $O(n^2)$ by back substitution method. I tried to rewrite $ST-\lambda I$ as the product of 2 matrixes, but it failed. Now I get stuck on this puzzling problem. Appreciated for any suggestions.

Comment: Isn't the set of upper triangular matrices closed under product? If it is, then $ST-\lambda I$ would be an upper triangular matrix.

Comment: @GonzaloAlejandroBenavidesGa But can you compute all the elements of $ST - \lambda I$ in $O(n^2)$?

Comment: The multiplication and sum of matrices are $\mathcal O (n^2)$.

Comment: Sorry, multiplication of triangular matrices*

Comment: If $\lambda$ is given, the problem is trivial - the matrix in brackets is upper triangular

Comment: @gt6989b How can I compute $ST$ in $O(n^2)$ (although $S,T$ are triangular) ?

Comment: @GonzaloAlejandroBenavidesGa: How do you  multiply upper triangular matrices in $n^2$?

Comment: Have a look on [this paper](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/ResearchPDF/ProdShift.ps) pages 1-2.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Thank you very much for your help. That's exactly what I  need.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel: Nice find.

Comment: @GonzaloAlejandroBenavidesGa: I believe that multiplying two upper triangular matrices is $O(n^3)$. Can you elaborate your assertion above please?

Comment: It seems the link provided by @AlgebraicPavel no longer works. I believe the paper they mentioned to be   _Product Triangular Systems with Shift, SIAM J. Matrix Analysis and Applications, 24(2002), 292-301_  for future comers of this problem.